# In a noSQL setting, what is an efficient way to search for child nodes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, database-design, nosql

In my noSQL database, I have a tree `users` which looks as follows:

```
users
     /simplelogin:1
          /email: a@a.com
          /username: albert
     /simplelogin:2
          /email: b@b.com
          /username: benihana
```

If I now wish to check whether the username benihana is taken, I would need to extract all the data from the tree users and then iterate over the childs `child(uid).child(username)` to see whether I can find a match.

This seems to me a very slow way as it can take some time to retrieve the data when you have a tree of let's say 10000 users.

What are therefore good practices to structure the data to make a query like the one above more efficient?

One option that I was thinking of is to create another tree usernames and the fill them with all the current usernames; e.g.:

```
usernames
     /benihana
          /uid: simplelogin:2
     /...
```

Then looking up the username requires checking whether the node `usernames/benihana` exists.

However, this requires many functions to be built in like "**add/edit/remove** `username` in `users`" and also in "**add/edit/remove** `username` in `usernames`", which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get all users to check their user name. Instead you can use a [Firebase query](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) to get the user you can looking for:

```
ref.orderByChild('username').equalTo('albert').on('value', ...
```

Creating a separate section in your tree for the user names is a common pattern in Firebase (and other NoSQL databases). In your case you're creating a map from the user's name to their uid, which is commonly called an index.

You'll probably want to [secure/validate](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) the data being written, so that only `simplelogin:1` can write `/usernames/albert`.

```
{ rules: {
  "usernames": {
    "$username": {
      // can only write if there is no data in this place yet AND
      // the user can only write their own data
      ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.val() == auth.uid",
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      "username": {
        // validate that the /username/$username has out $uid associated with it
        ".validate": "root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Note that I didn't test the above, so it is possible there are some problems with it. But this approach shows how I would secure this operation in Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for that. That makes sense. However, I mean more how do I search for the substr 'alb' when I am trying to find albert. Moreover, return a list of all usernames with as input 'alb'

Comment: `ref.orderByChild('username').startsWith('alb').endsWith('alc')` or `endsWith('al~')` if your only care about ASCII names. Please read the Firebase guide on querying as it covers this and more in greater detail than I can here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: As long as you only care about names that consist of only ASCII characters, the tilde (`~`) is **a nice little trick**. Since it has ASCII value, it falls after all ASCII alphanumeric characters. But note that in general it's probably safer to use a query that includes slightly too much (`alc` in the snippet above) and exclude the wrongfully queried ones in code.